# AccessDeniedException when trying to zip folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, java.nio.file

I want to zip a directory and it is content and download with REST request, but i get java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException error when i copy the directory.

```
public void downloadZipFile(String folderName, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.zip");

        try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
            FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(folderName);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(Objects.requireNonNull(fileSystemResource.getFilename()));
            zipEntry.setSize(fileSystemResource.contentLength());
            zipEntry.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            
            //The error is thrown here
            StreamUtils.copy(fileSystemResource.getInputStream(), zipOutputStream);

            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();

            zipOutputStream.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

folderName:

```
src\main\resources\images\marker-1
```

Comment: In jar file there is no directory such as src/main/resources. Maybe you can copy to different location.

Comment: You can check your target folder and see the structure there also you can move file under /tmp folder or different location.

Comment: You don't have read access to `folderName`. Not surprising if it really is a folder.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez changing directory does not solve the issue.

Comment: You can not use src/main/resource so at least you need to change folder location to tmp folder

Comment: The `src` directory isn't there at runtime. Check what is actually in the JAR or WAR file and use that path.